# Add hours from different sheets based on date

Tags: excel, date, logging

I have an Excel file where I have a few sheets. On one I keep track of my hours I work a the office. The other sheet is used to track the hours I spend travelling.

This is sheet1.

```
Date   Hours
27/11  8
28/11  8
29/11  7
```

This is sheet2.

```
Date   Hours
27/11  0
28/11  0
29/11  4
```

I would like to have a column on sheet1, that adds the hours depending on the dates. For example,

```
Date   Total Hours
27/11  8
28/11  8
29/11  11
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `SumProduct` or `SumIf` should be enough for you to do it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your date column starts in `A2`, this should work:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4)+Sheet1!B2
```

Answer (score 0):

The conventional solution is not to have the travel hours on a separate sheet in the first place (or if they are needed elsewhere to obtain them from the sheet1). When together with the office hours the data is more compact (e.g. the dates only entered once), so requires less storage space, the ‘picture’ provided by sheet1 ‘at a glance’ is more comprehensive (it may not be coincidence that the one day in the example showing travel time is also the one day with below average hours work at the office) – and the formula is simple, not requiring a question on SO, is easier to maintain, faster to process etc.

> I would like to have a column on sheet1, that adds the hours depending on the dates.

Assuming consistency in layout (e.g. say `Date` is in A1 on both sheets), then copying sheet2 ColumnB into sheet1 ColumnC, inserting `Total` into sheet1 D1 and entering:

```
=B2+C2
```

in sheet1 D2 and copying down would appear to meet your requirement and have the other advantages mentioned, though I suspect not quite the solution you wanted. In your last example you do not show the `Hours` column that you already had in sheet1 and if this is part of your objective you might, after the above, just hide ColumnsB:C.